# Iteriate rows on prawn pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn

I want to create multiple rows that will generate several orderlines from an orderid on prawn pdf but only one row of the orderline gets populated.

```
class OrderPdf < Prawn::Document

  def initialize(order, view)
    super(top_margin: 70)
    @order = order
    @view = view

     order_id
     products

  end

  def logo
    image_path =  "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/logo.jpg"

  end

  def order_id

    text "Invoice", size: 30, style: :bold, :align => :right

    font("Helvetica", :size => 11, style: :bold) do
      text "14077 Westheimer Rd"
      text "Houston, TX, 77077"
      text "Phone: 281-258-4940"
      text "Fax: 281-258-4947"
      text "AlphaOmegaFurniture.com"

      move_up 40

    text "INVOICE NO.   ##{@order.id}", :align => :right
    text "DATE:   #{@order.OrderDate}", :align => :right
    text  "CUSTOMER ID:   #{@order.Customer_id}", :align => :right

      move_down 40
      font_size 12
        text "To:    #{@order.Customer.fullName}"
        text "Phone: #{@order.ShipToPhone}"


      move_up 30
      font_size 12


      text "Ship To:    Name:        #{@order.Customer.fullName}", :indent_paragraphs => 200
      text "Address:   #{@order.ShipToAddress}", :indent_paragraphs => 260
      text "              #{@order.ShipToCity}, #{@order.ShipToState}, #{@order.ShipToZip}", :indent_paragraphs => 325
      text "Phone:       #{@order.ShipToPhone}", :indent_paragraphs => 260


  end

    move_down 20
    font_size 8

      data =[["SALES PERSON", "JOB", "SHIPPING METHOD", "SHIPPING TERMS", "DELIVERY DATE", "PAYMENT TERMS", "DUE DATE" ],
              ["#{@order.Employee.fullName}", "", "", "", "#{@order.EstimatedDeliveryDate}", "", "#{@order.OrderDate}"]

            ]
               table(data, :position => :left, :row_colors => ["F0F0F0", "FFFFCC"] ) do
                row(0).font_style = :bold

               end



    move_down 20
    font_size 8

    def products
      data =["PROVIDER", "QTY", "ITEM #", "DESCRIPTION", "UNIT PRICE", "DISCOUNT", "LINE TOTAL" ]

data2 = data

             OrderLine.all.each  do |orderline|


            data2 = ["", "", "#{orderline.Product_id}", "#{orderline.Order_id}", "#{orderline.Quantity}", "", ""]


             end

      data3 = [data,data2]
      table(data3, :position => :left, :row_colors => ["F0F0F0", "FFFFCC"], :column_widths => [60,60,60,180,60,60,60] )



end
      end
    end


class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /orders
  # GET /orders.json
  def index
    @orders = Order.all
  end

  # GET /orders/1
  # GET /orders/1.json
  def show

    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        pdf = OrderPdf.new(@order, view_context)

        send_data pdf.render, filename: "order_#{@order_id}.pdf",
                  type: "application/pdf",
                  disposition: "inline"

      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here some comments:

1._ Its better to relate Order to has many OrderLines. And get OrderLine array from Order parent because you will print always all the order_lines of all the orders.

For example: @order.lines

2._ Like you write each loop it always overwrite data2 with the last value. Its better to use something like this:

```
@table_data ||= OrderLine.all.map { |orderline| ["", "", "#{orderline.Product_id}", "#{orderline.Order_id}", "#{orderline.Quantity}", "", ""] }
```

The method products may work with something like this:

```
def products
 data =["PROVIDER", "QTY", "ITEM #", "DESCRIPTION", "UNIT PRICE", "DISCOUNT", "LINE TOTAL" ]
 table_data ||= OrderLine.all.map { |orderline| ["", "", "#{orderline.Product_id}", "#{orderline.Order_id}", "#{orderline.Quantity}", "", ""] }
 table(data, :position => :left, :row_colors => ["F0F0F0", "FFFFCC"], :column_widths => [60,60,60,180,60,60,60] )
 table(table_data, :position => :left, :row_colors => ["F0F0F0", "FFFFCC"], :column_widths => [60,60,60,180,60,60,60] )
end
```

I haven't test it. But you may have the idea.